# Send users through csv SFTP

Tags: uber-api

Why, in some accounts, when I send csv with many updates, does Uber just insert the users and keep the old ones? I also do not receive any warning emails about what happened. What can it be?

Comment: If you have some code or sample files, then please include them in your post.  It helps people to see what your doing.